# How can SSH server know private key is incorrect if passphrase havent been provided yet?

Tags: ssh

I have server which I am accessing via SSH. I only allow the authentication to be made with private key. Normally when I login via PuTTY, I am first asked for username and then asked for passphrase for the key. Out of curiosity I have created new private key, which should be invalid for my user and I also have put passphrase on it. To my surprise once I provided the user name the key attempted to login with to my server was refused before I have been asked for the passphrase.

I am wondering how can SSH server know that the private key is incorrect if the passphrase for it haven't been provided yet?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

While you've encrypted the private key, the public key is still readable. [SSH authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252) with the "[publickey](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-7)" method works by having the client send each potential public key to the server, then the server responds telling the client which key is allowed. If one of the keys is allowed, *then* the client must decrypt the private key to sign a message, proving ownership of the private key.

In your experiment, the server responded saying that none of the provided keys was allowed for your username, so there was no need to decrypt a private key, authentication had already failed.

Comment: Theortically a naughty client could send public keys for which it does not have the corresponding private key, correct?

Comment: @PyRulez Yes, but then the server will ask the client to prove it has the corresponding private key. Which it can't.

Comment: Could that information be abused, like testing with all public keys from github to find the owner of a server?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn You have to supply both username and public key. So you must already know that the username and key go together.

Comment: further, @JohannesKuhn, that would depend on the third party using the same public keys for managing servers as they do their github accounts.

Comment: If pubkey auth for root is used (which, contrary to a lot of misinformation, is not a bad practice, and generally has much smaller attack surface and lower risk than having su or sudo installed) then root would be a natural candidate to test.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn That's an interesting idea. As far as I recall OpenSSH by default enforce a limit of at most 10 public keys attempted per connection. However by default it doesn't limit the number of connection attempts a client can make, so the 10 public keys limit is more likely to hit legitimate users than to prevent the search you suggest. The most straightforward fix would cause a major nuisance to anybody using keys which require confirmation on every usage.

Comment: @JCRM Public keys are usually not considered to be sensitive, and for that reason it isn't generally considered bad practice to use the same key to log in to more than one location. If you do have multiple keys chances are you have `ssh` configured to try them all on each server where you log in. That means a list of all your public keys could easily leak, and it also means it's not practical to have more than 10 key pairs, as OpenSSH by default doesn't allow you to try more than 10.

Comment: @R.. I agree with that. There was a [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/66894/47143) about that in the past.

Comment: no, I have ssh configured to use the correct keys for the hosts I'm connecting to @kasperd. I share keys between hosts within  the security domain but not otherwise. Just as I wouldn't share usernames between them.

Comment: @JCRM I use kasperd as my username on every system that will allow me to. I don't see a need to choose a different username on every system that I use.

Comment: and that is your choice to make @kasperd

Answer (score 14):

During connection client will sent successively fingerprint of all availables keys to server.

When server signal to client a valid key found, client will use them, then ask for passphrase if needed.

Try to run ssh with debug option:

```
ssh -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 user@dest
```

look for fingerprint with

```
ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/id_rsa
```

For checking authorized_keys, line by line:

```
while read line;do
    ssh-keygen -l -f <(echo "$line")
  done <.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Note that instead of `-o LogLevel=DEBUG3` (lots of typing), `-vvv` (three times verbose) should also work.